# How does one repent and remain steadfast on the straight path?

Tags: salat, hijab, zina, tawba, depression

If one has repented and wants to be become a more practising Muslim but points below get in the way, how do they deal with them from an Islamic prospective?

- If one is prevented from praying while at work.
- Keeps on remembering sins committed in the past and feeling guilty
  because of them.
- Surrounded by a bad environment related to their life and habits
  before repenting. Feeling lonely with no one to care for and
  support.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! I am glad you are trying to get back on the right track, and we can assist in many ways. However, Islam.SE is not a peer support site. So you will need to ask specific questions about what Islam decrees for a defined situation, then we can answer. Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](//islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](//islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in our [help center](//islam.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: I believe this is now on-topic because of the edits made, as it is seeking an answer from an Islamic perspective rather than support

Answer (score 4):

The first thing you need to bare in mind is that Allah is the most forgiving and he is capable of forgiving any sin as long as repentance was a sincere one:

> Truly, Allah loves those who turn unto Him in repentance and loves
>   those who purify themselves. [Quran, 2:222]

Although sincere repentance may cause your sins to be forgiven, it isn't an easy task to attempt to remain stead fast on the righteous path and avoid sins:

> Do the people think that they will be left to say, "We believe" and
>   they will not be tried? [Quran, 29:2]

Life is a struggle and one should remain strong throughout their, one cannot achieve this by their own rather by supplicating to God and relying on him after you have done all that you could possibly do:

> And when My servants ask you, [O Muhammad], concerning Me - indeed I
>   am near. I respond to the invocation of the supplicant when he calls
>   upon Me. So let them respond to Me [by obedience] and believe in Me
>   that they may be [rightly] guided [Quran, 2:186]
>
> And He will provide him from (sources) he never could imagine. And
>   whosoever puts his trust in Allah, then He will suffice him. Verily,
>   Allah will accomplish his purpose. Indeed Allah has set a measure for
>   all things [Quran, 65:3]

Performing prayers is one of the most important factors that will help you in avoiding going back to your old sins:

> (and perform the Salah. Verily, the Salah prevents from Al-Fahsha' and
>   Al-Munkar and the remembrance of Allah is greater indeed.) [Quran, :]

Your employer has no right to prevent you from doing this and in many countries (even non-muslim countries) this is considered as discremenation in the work place therefore know your rights and excersise them if not find a new employer and Allah will help you in the process:

> Abu Qatadah reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him,
>   said, “Verily, you will never leave anything for the sake of Allah
>   Almighty but that Allah will replace it with something better.”
>   Source: Musnad Aḥmad 22565

Changing the environment your in and those around you that have a bad influence on you is essential for you to remain a righteous person:

> And keep yourself (O Muhammad SAW) patiently with those who call on
>   their Lord (i.e. your companions who remember their Lord with
>   glorification, praising in prayers, etc., and other righteous deeds,
>   etc.) morning and afternoon, seeking His Face, and let not your eyes
>   overlook them, desiring the pomp and glitter of the life of the world;
>   and obey not him whose heart We have made heedless of Our Remembrance,
>   one who follows his own lusts and whose affair (deeds) has been lost. [Quran, 18:28]

Answer (score 2):

Rainnerw,

Life is a continuous struggle, you are on the correct path, you certainly know it .. but you need more weapons to empower you in that struggle.

Several points to answer your long question:

- Tawbaa will be accepted by Allah even if the same sin is repeated, as long as you are <sup>[[1](http://www.binbaz.org.sa/fatawa/4251)]</sup>:

  - Sorry of what you have done
  - Have stopped, and Cut any current link with that sin
  - Truely and surely willing not to return to that sin again
- The best weapon for your case is changing the environment you are used to. Find a charity group to join, Quran study group or a volunteer activities within the Islamic community around. There's a well-known saying: "If you do not make yourself busy with good deeds, it will make you busy with bad ones".
- Change your working place for a more Islamic-friendly culture: Salat cannot be compromised
- Romantic desires are built-in all of us. Ask Allah in your prayers to give you a loving practicing Muslim husband. Keep patient untill your prayers are granted. Allah gives uncounted rewards for those who have patience.